# Scilab installation tcl tk configure not working

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, software-installation, programming, matlab

I am installing Scilab 4.1.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 manually. I entered the folder and pressed ./configure but after some steps it shows

> configure: error: header file tcl.h has been found for 8.4*  but no corresponding tcl library (ie libtcl8.4.so)

How to resolve this problem? Directly installing Scilab will install the latest version of Scilab but i need to install previous versions.

Comment: Try installing the tcl dev library with `sudo apt-get install tcl8.4-dev`

Comment: Already installed. Still the problem persists.